# How do I get a specific value inside an URL?

Tags: php

I would like to know how I could get a specific value from an URL.
For example I have this url (could be any with different ID/Name):

```
https://myforum.com/index.php?/profile/600-Ninja/
```

I would like to only get the member ID (the numbers right before his name)

```
$userURL = "https://myforum.com/index.php?/profile/600-Ninja/";
$userID = preg_match..?

echo $userID;
```

*Desired output: "600"*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Hey, sorry if I done anything the wrong way, I am beginning in php that's why I am asking this question, because I don't know how to do it

Comment: You need to show us your best attempt (code) and tell us what exactly does not work as expected. Do you get any error message(s)? Debugging effort(s)?

Comment: No, no I just know it is possible but I don't know how it works with preg_replace() so I would like to know if someone knows how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Uset the `parse_url` function, then strip out all the non-digits with `preg_replace`

```
<?php
$userURL = "https://myforum.com/index.php?/profile/600-Ninja/";
$url = parse_url($userURL);
var_dump($url);
$userID = preg_replace('/\D/','',$url['query']);
echo 'User id: '.$userID.PHP_EOL;
```

- Apologies if you wanted to only use a regular expression, the objective of this answer is to get the user id, not explain a regular expression approach

Comment: could shorten it (abit) with `PHP_URL_QUERY`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - I agree

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the right server request parameter and start there. In this case, you'd need the query string of your request URI. So you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/parse_url) to extract your effective path. I'd personally use [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/preg_match) to check the route before using the value(s):

```php
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['query'] ?? '/';
if (preg_match($regex, $path, $matches)) {
        // ...
}
```

As with regular expression, you can test it with web platform like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) and test it. Since I have no idea your complete use case, it is impossible for me to write the complete code for you. But the below regex would work for the specific case you mentioned:

```php
if (preg_match('/^\/(?<type>[[:alnum:]_-]+)\/(?<id>\d+)(?<id_extra>[[:alnum:]_-]*)(?<trailing_slash>\/|)$/', $path, $matches)) {
        $userID = $matches['id'];
        // ...
}
```